# creating ado recordset from fso object

Tags: asp-classic, recordset

i have a fso object the gets all files in directory.
i want to create a recordset of the file name, size and date created so i will be able to sort the recordset by date.

what i tried is:

```
Dim rs
set rs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")     

-----------> rs.fields.append "Name", 201

rs.fields.append "Size", 201
rs.fields.append "Date", 7

RS.Open()
fld1 = RS.Fields("Name")
fld2 = RS.Fields("Size")
fld3 = RS.Fields("Date")
rs.close
```

i get error: Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another on the with the arrow

**NEVER MIND: error was for reserved words**

sulution is to have the name of the field in "[" and "]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `.Open` you must `.Addnew` in order to create a row to which you can assign your values.

Also I would use `rs.fields.append "Size", 201, 255` (200=advarchar; 255=max len) instead of the longvarchar 201 which iirc is implemented as a blob so is not as performant.

Comment: i have addnew in the rest of the code... but what about the error i'm getting? i already tried changing from 201 to 200, and tried the 255 length